# jquery callback function

Tags: jquery, function, callback, recaptcha

i use recaptcha

```
Recaptcha.create("xxx", "recaptcha", {
            theme: 'clean',
            tabindex: 0,
            callback: $("#id").focus
        });
```

i want to use callback to focus some field, but it doesn't work, only `callback: f` works

```
 function f() {
        $("#FIO").focus();
    }
```

what is the problem?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The callback needs to be a function.  What you have attempts to execute the $() function and reference the focus method of it.  That won't work.  Try this.

```
Recaptcha.create("xxx", "recaptcha", {
        theme: 'clean',
        tabindex: 0,
        callback: function() { $("#id").focus(); }
    });
```

Answer (score 0):

Are you sure the result of the statement `$("#FIO").focus()` is consistent across scopes?

or try this?`callback: function() { $("#FIO").focus(); }`

Answer (score 0):

The `focus()` is also native function of javascript, you can do in either way

```
callback: function(){$("#id").focus();}
```

or

```
callback: function(){$("#id")[0].focus();}
```